# Anchoring Gazebo in planter pot

Tags: backyard

I am planning to buy a 3x3m gazebo. I will be putting it in my backyard. The backyard has pavers, so the gazebo legs will go on the pavers. The pavers are about 20cm apart. As far as I think, the pavers are secured to the ground, so it may be hard to remove.

I want to secure the gazebo, i.e. anchor it somehow so that it does not move or is blown away by strong wind. I am looking for an easier and cost-effective option (over digging, drilling or screwing).

**One solution is to put the gazebo legs in a wide/square planter pot and secure the leg into the pot with concrete.** This is similar to digging a hole in the ground and securing it with concrete, except that it will be above ground.

The end result will be four planter pots holding the gazebo down. I am thinking of leaving some space at the top of the planter pot, so that I can fill it with soil and plants some flowers, thus disguising the weight.

**My question is which type of planter pot should I use** (e.g. terracotta, fibreglass etc.). My concern is whether the pot would be able to hold the leg and concrete without cracking.

Another thought is that, instead of putting concrete in the planter pot, I may be able to secure the gazebo leg in it by some other way (e.g. tying it to the pot and then filling it with soil to make the pot heavy.

I am unsure if the above is feasible.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A structure that big on four (?) legs would put a whole lot of force on those pavers, probably pushing them into the ground. You should really consider removing (destroying if you have to) pavers so you can dig post holes. The results would be far more durable and wind-resistant.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, concrete in a planter would most likely crack it due to its expansion and contraction caused by changes in humidity and temperature. However, a plastic 5-gallon bucket will hold concrete, and you could camouflage the bucket by putting it in a planter and covering it with dirt. Depending on where you live, four 5-gallon buckets of concrete might not be enough to guarantee your gazebo won't be moved by wind (thereby bending and destroying it.) You could consider using half wine barrels filled with concrete instead. I would expect 4 of those to be an adequate anchor.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you offered and wanting to do the least amount of work the only idea I can offer is to use concrete form stakes. These flat steel stakes are used to secure forms that concrete is poured into. They are sold in varying lengths (12-36 inches) and are easily hammered into the earth.

If your pavers don't have an open joint for the stakes to pass through you will need to make one. Mark the legs position on the ground and drive the stake to whatever edge of the leg most appropriate suited for your needs.

The stakes have openings for fasteners that you can use to attach the legs to and keep it ridged.